# Converting seconds into HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript)

Hi,

I have a float of 16.4534, which is the seconds of a duration of a video. I want to convert this into HH:MM:SS so it would look like 00:00:16.

Have done a search but haven't found anything relavent.

Do I need to use a regex?

Help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for seconds to MM:SS format convesation refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652857/14344959

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```js
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);

    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    return ('0' + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + s).slice(-2);
}

document.writeln('secondsToHms(10) = ' + secondsToHms(10) + '<br>');
document.writeln('secondsToHms(30) = ' + secondsToHms(30) + '<br>');
document.writeln('secondsToHms(60) = ' + secondsToHms(60) + '<br>');
document.writeln('secondsToHms(100) = ' + secondsToHms(100) + '<br>');
document.writeln('secondsToHms(119) = ' + secondsToHms(119) + '<br>');
document.writeln('secondsToHms(500) = ' + secondsToHms(500) + '<br>');
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, but I combined it with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6313008/396381) modifying the first two lines to `Number.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
   d = this;` to make it even more concise.

Comment: Nice - I corrected a small bug where for  h > 0 and m = 0 it wasn't padding the minutes to 00. I've submitted it as an edit to your answer, as the question is closed to new answers.

Comment: You can use moment.js: `moment().startOf('day').seconds(16.4534).format('HH:mm:ss')`   -  it's as simple as that.

Comment: If the seconds == 0, this returns 0:00 instead of what I would expect to be 00:00:00

Comment: The answer above can be improved by conditional return value like this `if (h > 0) {
      return (
        ("0" + h).slice(-2) +
        ":" +
        ("0" + m).slice(-2) +
        ":" +
        ("0" + s).slice(-2)
      );
    }

    return ("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2);` to avoid 00 when the time has not reached hour

Comment: Another option to omit unneeded sections is to add the values to an array, then return the array joined with a colon separator.
`const parts = [('0' + s).slice(-2)];`
`if (m || (!m && h)) parts.unshift(('0' + m).slice(-2));`
`if (h) parts.unshift(('0' + h).slice(-2));`
`return parts.join(":");`