# BrightCove Video Duration Data type

Tags: javascript, brightcove

How we convert Bright Cove video duration to HH:MM:SSS in Javascript?

Comment: Please take more than 10s to post your question. Then you might get the tags right, plus the spelling and capitalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brightcove's API returns the duration in milliseconds. Divide by 1000 then apply one of the answers for formatting seconds as HH:MM:SS e.g. [JavaScript seconds to time string with format hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-with-format-hhmmss)