# New JavaScript date object from seconds of a day

Tags: javascript, date, time

Seems simple but I can't figure it out. *sigh*

I have **74141** as seconds in a day, how do I create a Date object from this number to represent the time in hours and seconds? The actual date I don't care about because I'm just going to be using getHours/Seconds/Minutes to set another date which has the correct date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-with-format-hhmmss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Date.prototype.setSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds) for this purpose.
You don't really need to worry about conversion, as that is automatic:

```
var date = new Date(1970, 0, 1); 
date.setSeconds(secs);
```

The above trick relies on the fact that the `Date` points exactly to midnight, so the timing
you get back is precise. For precision reasons, I am using EPOCH, although any "exact" midnight would do.

Comment: Just setting the seconds field will work if you *know* that you've got a date object representing precisely midnight on a particular day. If the date object represents another time of day, then the date internals will "fix" the time by *adding* the excess seconds.

Comment: Yes that'll make it work, and any other date will work too when you construct the Date instance like you're doing in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the date

   ```
    var now = new Date();
   ```
2. Zero out the time-of-day fields:

   ```
    now.setHours(0).setMinutes(0).setSeconds(0).setMilliseconds(0);
   ```
3. Create a new time from your time-of-day number:

   ```
    var theTime = new Date(now.getTime() + timeInSeconds * 1000);
   ```

You could of course use a Date instance representing any other date, but it seems like using the current date would be the least weird thing to do (barring some other conditions).

*edit* — actually after zeroing out the time fields, you could just use `.setSeconds()` with your value and avoid creating a new object. It's probably not a big issue one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to alex23's answer, it's enough to give 0 as date construction param.

```
var date = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
// same as
var date = new Date(0);
```