# Cannot convert second to minute format

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script to call Youtube video duration, but it's formatted in seconds. Now, I want to change it to minutes. How can I do it with this script?

```
function youtubeFeedCallback(json){
  document.write(json["data"]["duration"]);
}

var stimer = "<script src=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+vidid+"?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=youtubeFeedCallback&prettyprint=true\"><\/script>";
document.write('<div class="time">'+ stimer +'</div>');
```

**For example:**

Time duration: 300 s

After conversion: 5 min.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

```
var min = (json["data"]["duration"] /60);
var sec = ( json["data"]["duration"] % 60);
var hour = (min / 60 ); 
min = (min % 60 );
document.write(hour + " : "+min+" : "+sec);
```

Comment: Tks for your help. But it is not formatted yet. However, your suggestion also help me to solve this by check with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-with-format-hhmmss

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.write(json["data"]["duration"]/60);
```