# How do I calculate a total time

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am developing a web-based application to capture total time of playlist of video. my main problem is that I don't know how can I calculate the total time from an array e.g: 30:00 + 30:00 = 01:00. Time is in mm:ss output I need in hh:mm

```
var time = ["13:24", "4:28", "7:29"];

for (k in time){
    add(time[k].split(":"));
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into moment durations http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: I believe that this questions belongs to maths rather than programming

Comment: I want to do this with core javascript without using any jquery plugin or  library

Comment: An example that should give you the information you need. It get the time from a table rather than an array, but otherwise it seems to be what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090857/calculate-the-sum-of-the-time-for-column/17091483#17091483

Comment: What does your `add` function do?

Comment: I was writing add function to calculate the time

Comment: I think he means, can we see the code of your `add` function, we kind of know it's a function for adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of what you could do.

```js
// assuming num will always be positive
function zeroPad(num) {
  var str = String(num);
  if (str.length < 2) {
    return '0' + str;
  }

  return str;
}

// assuming your time strings will always be (H*:)(m{0,2}:)s{0,2} and never negative
function totalTimeString(timeStrings) {
  var totals = timeStrings.reduce(function (a, timeString) {
    var parts = timeString.split(':');
    var temp;
    if (parts.length > 0) {
      temp = Number(parts.pop()) + a.seconds;
      a.seconds = temp % 60;
      if (parts.length > 0) {
        temp = (Number(parts.pop()) + a.minutes) + ((temp - a.seconds) / 60);
        a.minutes = temp % 60;
        a.hours = a.hours + ((temp - a.minutes) / 60);
        if (parts.length > 0) {
          a.hours += Number(parts.pop());
        }
      }
    }

    return a;
  }, {
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0
  });

  // returned string will be HH(H+):mm:ss
  return [
    zeroPad(totals.hours),
    zeroPad(totals.minutes),
    zeroPad(totals.seconds)
  ].join(':');
}

var result1 = totalTimeString([
  '13:24',
  '4:28',
  '7:29'
]);

console.log(result1);

var result2 = totalTimeString([
  '13:24:06',
  '4:28:46',
  '17:29:11'
]);

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: @Xotic750 how to add hours to this code?
totalTimeString(["13:24:06", "4:28:46", "17:29:11"]);

Comment: @akuljana See update

Answer (score 1):

Here is the good example for you...

keep your above loop and slip it into Hours and Minutes and assign it as per below dt.setHours and Minutes

this will be more helpful

```js
var dt = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + 1);      // For the 01:00
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 30); // For the first 00:30
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes()+ 25); // For the second 00:30


display(dt.getHours() + " : " + dt.getMinutes());

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: OP says: `I need in hh:mm`

Comment: Thanks! i missed that part but doing the same to setHours function this will works! no big deal...  negating on this crazy...

Comment: xotic750: thanks for correcting me hope it will work!