# Javascript converting second to minutes

Tags: javascript

So far I have been able to find the sum of min and sec store in array

```
var time = ["13:24", "4:28", "7:29"];
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
for (k in time){
    min += +time[k].split(":")[0];
    sec += +time[k].split(":")[1];
}
var rem = sec % 60;
min += rem;

alert(min+'-'+sec);  //25-81
```

my desired output it `25-21`

Comment: Also you have a simple array, use `for (var i=0;i<time.length;i++) ...time[i]` and not the `for in` construct

Comment: Is there some kind of homework question going on here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619485/how-do-i-calculate-a-total-time

Comment: Or use forEach: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wL9bb8ab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the desired o/p is 25-21

```js
var time = ["13:24", "4:28", "7:29"];
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;

var minsec = time.forEach(function(time) {
  var parts = time.split(":")
  min += +parts[0];
  sec += +parts[1];
});

//Add the whole minutes from the seconds ie if seconds is 130 then 2 minuste to be added to min
min += Math.floor(sec / 60);
//then the rest 10 secs to be added to sec
sec = sec % 60;

alert(min + '-' + sec);
```

Comment: For in is not recommended on arrays. Here is a forEach version https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wL9bb8ab/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is wrong. You're adding the modulo of `sec` to `min`. That means if you were on 59 seconds, you'd add 59 minutes to your sum.

Instead you should add the division of `sec`, and set `sec` to the modulo:

```
min += Math.floor(sec / 60);
sec %= 60;
```

This way 69 seconds would translate to 1 minute and 9 seconds, whereas your current code would compute 9 minutes and 69 seconds.