# Countdown timer in javascript using setTimeout

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i'm creating a countdown timer using jquery, i refered to a few example here and came out with the following codes. The problem is the time doesn't show, and i can't figure out what is wrong. Been stuck for almost 2 hours..

back code

```
    var day = 1;                        //countdown time
    var start = player.LastActive;      // Use UtcNow instead of Now
    var endTime = start.AddDays(day);   //endTime is a member, not a local variable
    Timespan remainingTime = endTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
```

my javascript

```
var endTime = '<%= remainingTime%>';
var startTime = '<%= DateTime.UtcNow %>'

$(document).load(function () {
        countDown(endTime);
    });

    function countDown(endTime) {
        if (endTime > 0) {
            var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");
            d.innerHTML = endTime;
            setTimeout(function () { countDown(endTime - 1); }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

my html

```
<div id="countDiv" style="float:left;margin-top: 13px; margin-left:5px;"></div>
```

my goal is to show how long more, for a player to get his daily move : which is a day after the players lastactive time. Can someone enlighten me..thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(window).load`

or

```
$(document).ready
```

but not `$(document).load`

and as you seem to use jquery, you can do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        countDown(endTime);
    });

    function countDown(endTime) {
        if (endTime > 0) {
            $('#countDiv').text(secondsToTime(endTime));
            setTimeout(function () { countDown(endTime - 1); }, 1000);
        }
    }
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    return hours +':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
```

for seconds to time, it's coming from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312999/961526 , you may take another version which you can find there.

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rju6m/2/)

Comment: thanks for the reply but it's still the same after i followed yr method

Comment: @GopinathKoothaperumal well, maybe some problem with your endTime, because see : http://jsfiddle.net/rju6m/1/

Comment: yes, i solved it. did this var endTime = '<%= remainingTime.totalseconds%>'; one last question, how do i convert the totalseconds into 00:00:00 this format

Answer (score 2):

Since your endtime is string in your javascript code, convert it integer first

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        countDown(parseInt(endTime));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ready`, not `load`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  countDown(endTime);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

```
  $(function() {
            countDown(endTime);
       });

 function countDown(parseInt(endTime)) {
        if (endTime > 0) {
            $('#countDiv').text(endTime);
            setTimeout(function () { countDown(endTime - 1); }, 1000);
        }
    }
```