# cant auto submit after countdown

Tags: php, form-submit, countdown, countdowntimer

please help, theres 2 things i want to asking about:

1. with that script, the count down just show an number, iwant the countdown shown 
   as time format --:--:--
2. i cant auto submit after the countdown finish, and the count down wont stop after zero.

   ```
   <script>
   function timeOut(){
   alert("timeout");
   document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();
   }       
   (function () {
   var timeLeft = <?php echo ($data_test['TIME'] * 60) - $tb ?>,
       cinterval;

   var timeDec = function (){
       timeLeft--;
       document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timeLeft;
       if(timeLeft === 0){
           timeOut();
           clearInterval(cinterval);
       }
   };

   cinterval = setInterval(timeDec, 1000);
   })();
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = 11; // Whatever.
function myTimer(interval){
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = --interval;
  if (interval > 0) setTimeout(function(){myTimer(interval);}, 1000);
  else document.forms['myFormId'].submit();
}
myTimer(interval);
```

Something along these lines. Could be a lot better, but it's really just to give you an example right here. Shouldn't be much of a hazle.

Edit:
Also see [JavaScript seconds to time string with format hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-with-format-hhmmss) for the formatting.

Comment: thanks for your help, now the timer stop at zero, but still the autosubmit wont work and the timer back to start when i refresh it