# Countdown in hrs/minutes/seconds in php function using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

I have tried alot of things but i don't know really much about javascript. I have a countdown script but it only countdown in seconds but i need hours minutes and seconds.

This is the code:

```
function countDown($i, $verschil){

$msg = "

<script type='text/javascript'>
     var seconds". $i."=". $verschil.";
     function display". $i."()
     {
       seconds". $i."=seconds". $i."-1;
       if(seconds". $i."<0)
       {
          countdown". $i.".innerHTML=\"0\";
       }
        else
        {
           var countdown". $i." = document.all? document.all[\"cd".$i."\"] : document.getElementById ? document.getElementById (\"cd". $i."\")
           : \"\";
           if (countdown". $i.")
          {
            countdown". $i.".innerHTML=seconds". $i.";
            setTimeout('display". $i."()',1000);
          }
       }
     }
    display". $i."();
  </script>

";

return $msg;

}
```

- **$i** = name of countdown, **$verschil** = Seconds to countdown

I hope someone can help me, tried things for almost 20 hours but i can't get this working.

Comment: Just look for a jquery plugin for this?

Comment: You are using the above code, right?

Comment: You must mixing javascript and PHP like this ? It's ugly.

Comment: @Utkarsh Yes thats the code in the script

Comment: @Debflav Unfortunately yes :(

Comment: So this has not really anything to do with PHP. You have put it IN PHP but the question is about the JS code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-with-format-hhmmss

Comment: Are you sure that you have to mix PHP and JS ? Someting like http://jsfiddle.net/tj4gqvd8/ would be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.. I just wrote it without chekcing it.. No Promis this works

```
function countDown($name, $time){

$seconds = gmdate("G", $time);
$minutes = gmdate("i", $time);
$hours   = gmdate("s", $time);

$msg = "

<script type='text/javascript'>
     var seconds".$name."=".$seconds."
     var minutes".$name."=".$minutes."
     var hours".$name."=".$hours."
     function display". $name."()
     {
        if(hours".$name." != 0 && minutes".$name." != 0 && seconds".$name." != 0) {
            if(seconds".$name." > 0) {
                seconds".$name." = seconds".$name."-1;
            } else {
                if(minutes".$name." > 0) {
                    minutes".$name." = minutes".$name."-1;
                } else {
                    hours".$name."= hours".$name."-1;
                }
            }

            var countdown".$name." = document.all? document.all[\"cd".$name."\"] : document.getElementById ? document.getElementById (\"cd". $name."\")
           : \"\";
           if (countdown". $name.")
          {
            countdown". $name.".innerHTML= ''+hours".$name."+':'+minutes".$name."+':'+seconds".$name.";
            setTimeout('display". $name."()',1000);
          }

        } else {
            countdown". $name.".innerHTML=\"0:0:0\";
        }
     }
    display". $name."();
  </script>

";

return $msg;

}
```

Note: This mixed style is a bad codig style... for testing ok but you should try to avoid it

Comment: Doens't work, But still thanks for your help!

Comment: Hm.. but you could try to fix it :D

Comment: I fixed it, but now the countdown is lagging. it's only counting down when mouse is moving

Comment: hm... thats strange how are you calling the display function?