# What is the best way of converting Fri Nov 28 2014 16:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time) to 2014-11-28 16:00:00 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

`Fri Nov 28 2014 16:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)` to `2014-11-28 16:00:00`
I want the conversion to be in javascript only. In php some minutes goes up and down when i m using

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Wed Nov 26 2014 04:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)));`
gives me : `1970-01-01 05:30:00`.

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time(Wed Nov 26 2014 03:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)));` gives me `2014-11-26 17:32:04`

2mins and 4secs are extra.

Thanks.

Comment: Try moment.js or date.js to simplify handling dates. Doing it in vanilla JS is a nightmare.

Comment: Can you just post the method. Which one to use and type of function to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date("Fri Nov 28 2014 16:00:00 GMT 0530");
console.log(getFormattedString(d));
function getFormattedString(d){
  return d.getFullYear() + "-"+(d.getMonth()+1) +"-"+d.getDate() + ' '+d.toString().split(' ')[4];
  // for time part you may wish to refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use moment.js

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Something like that.

But you should dig a little bit more around here.. There are many similar questions

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/