# Timer not formatting correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a timer that works exactly how i want it except when it counts down it displays 2:0 when it should display 2:00. It also displays 1:00,1:01,1:02 etc as 1:0,1:1,1:2 etc . However 1:59 through 1:11 and 0:11 through 0:59 does display correctly. Basicly it is having and issue display 0-9 seconds correctly. Here is my code and a codepen

js

```
 $(function () {
  var $startTimer = $('#startTimer');
  var $timerDisplay = $('#timerDisplay');
  var time = 120;

  $timerDisplay.hide();

  $startTimer.click(function () {
    $startTimer.prop('disabled', true);
    $timerDisplay.show();
    var timeRemaining = time;
     var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
     var timeStamp = Math.floor(timeRemaining/60) + ':' +    timeRemaining%60;
       $timerDisplay.text(timeStamp);
         if (timeRemaining === 0) {
         clearInterval(intervalId);
        $timerDisplay.fadeOut();
        alert('Time is up, please submit a vote :)');
        $startTimer.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
        timeRemaining--;
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

html

```
<div id="timerDisplay"></div>
<button id="startTimer">Start Timer</button>
```

here is a codepen http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/RNomGG

Comment: This is a standard "how do I display a number with a fixed number of digits" problem. There are 100s of answers out there (and on SO).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript seconds to time string with format hh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

You need to zero pad the number given by `timeRemaining%60`

There are a number of ways to zero pad in Javascript.

For this application, as it's specific, I recommend replacing:

```
var timeStamp = Math.floor(timeRemaining/60) + ':' +    timeRemaining%60;
```

with

```
var seconds = timeRemaining%60;
seconds = ("0" + seconds).slice (-2);
var timeStamp = Math.floor(timeRemaining/60) + ':' +  seconds;
```

This works by zero padding every variable seconds and then taking the last two digits - e.g. `0` becomes `00`, but `57` becomes `057`, but then the slice takes the last two.