# What is the best way to reload a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload

Can someone help me with what is the best away to make a div reload? for example a div with a timer.

Exemple:

```
<div id="clock"> 00:00:00 </div>
```

And i need that to reload every 1s like

```
<div id="clock"> 00:00:00 </div>
<div id="clock"> 00:00:01 </div>
<div id="clock"> 00:00:02 </div>
<div id="clock"> 00:00:03 </div>
```

Comment: `window.setInterval` can do this for you where it will update the contents of the element at a specific interval (ie `1000` or 1 sec)

Comment: don't reload it. just have some JS code write the updated time to the div, replacing whatever time was there before.

Comment: You can use a real time system, something like Socket.IO (node.js)

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// Update the div
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "the new value";
}, 1000);
```

This is going to set a new content to the div every second (1000 miliseconds)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use javascript to make a "timer-like" updating div, in an `hh:mm:ss` format, you can use `setInterval` and a parsing function (taken from [@powtac's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)):

```js
var startTime = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
  $("#clock").html(toHHMMSS(startTime.toString()));
  startTime++;
}, 1000);


function toHHMMSS(str) {
  var sec_num = parseInt(str, 10); // don't forget the second param
  var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  return time;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock">00:00:00</div>
```