# Stopwatch/countdown (00:00:00) format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I have this code:

```
    function startStopwatch() {
        vm.lastTickTime = new Date();

        $interval.cancel(vm.timerPromise);
        vm.timerPromise = $interval(function() {
            var tickTime = new Date();
            var dateDiff = vm.lastTickTime.getTime() - tickTime.getTime();
            var secondsDiff = Math.abs(dateDiff / 1000);
            vm.secondsElapsed += Math.round(secondsDiff);
            vm.formattedSecondsElapsed = moment.duration(secondsElapsed, "seconds").format("HH:mm:ss");
            vm.lastTickTime = tickTime;
        }, 1000);
    }
```

It ticks seconds (int) since the 'play' button was hit on a stopwatch.

But the format is `01`, `02`.... up to 60 and then `01:01`, `01:02`, etc.

I'd like to format it as `00:00:00`, incrementing the int.  I've found answers for other programming languages but not JavaScript.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: woah downvoter: this is a well thought out question with supporting code...

Comment: Why don't you build your own conversion function - it shouldn't be too hard? Not sure if something out-of-the-box exists for this purpose. Whenever I needed something like that, I was building my own in a few minutes... But it's possible there's a way to do it with moment, let's wait for an answer.

Comment: yeah I'm hoping somebody knows a handy answer off the top of their head. I'm really confused about the downvote. I'll roll my own function and post it if I need to.

Comment: If you get no answers in, say, 10 minutes, I'll help you write your own function. Don't worry about the downvoters - there are a couple of them that randomly go and downvote everything... :/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess that maybe the person who did did so because your question doesn't show any attempt to fix the problem: it basically says "I wish this code did something else". You said in a comment you'd roll your own function if you need to - why not do that first? Best way to learn. Read the Moment documentation. If you get stuck, *then* ask about it in this forum.

Comment: There are tons of answers, did you see them @RJB? This one looks good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss

Comment: I was searching for a while but I didn't see that post. Thanks, solid answer.

Comment: Haha, it was the first I found. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from the answer provided by RJB, convert the algorithm to a filter:

## Filter

```
app.filter('time', function() { 
    function isInt(n){
        return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
    }
    return function(val) {
        if (isInt(val))
            return new Date(null, null, null, null, null, val).toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");

        return val;
    }
});
```

## Usage

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.seconds = 25251;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
      {{ seconds | time }}
</div>
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MhZ92vbl6vudLILbvBck?p=info)

Comment: Thanks for taking the question seriously. This is great; I had originally hoped to use filters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to undelete this because I think this is the best answer and I think it has academic value.

```
vm.durationElapsed = new Date(null, null, null, null, null, secondsElapsed).toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
```

Answer found on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612778/1507899

Comment: I think you should close it, and upvote the original answer there.

Comment: It's a modification based on one of the comments of the answer.  His answer modifies a Date; this formats seconds elapsed -- more useful for a stopwatch.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fair enough!