# Creating a startstoptimer - not working

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I'm obviously new to this, and I can't get my head around this problem.

I'm creating a timer that stops and starts, afterwards the startstoptimes have to be stored in Mysql.

But for now I can't even get the timer to work properly.
I'd like the time formatted as hh:mm.
And the totaltime gives me a number for some reason...

This is a code so far:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Timer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" media="all" />
  <div>
    <?php include 'menu.php';?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var t;
      var timer_is_on = 0;
      var StartTime = new Date();
      var RunTime = new Date();
      var EndTime = new Date();;
      var TotalTime = new Date();

      function timedCount() {
        var RunTime = new Date();
        document.getElementById('runtime').value = RunTime;
        t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
      }

      function doTimer() {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
          var StartTime = new Date();
          document.getElementById('starttime').value = StartTime;
          timer_is_on = 1;
          timedCount();
        }
      }

      function stopCount() {
        var EndTime = new Date();
        var EndTimeMs = EndTime.getTime();
        TotalTime = EndTime - StartTime;
        document.getElementById('totaltime').value = TotalTime;
        clearTimeout(t);
        timer_is_on = 0;
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()" />
    <input type="text" id="starttime" />
    <input type="text" id="runtime" />
    <input type="text" id="totaltime" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop count!" onclick="stopCount()" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get value in milliseconds. You can use then function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss) to display time the way you want after computation.