# create timer effect in format 'MM:SS:MS'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a timer and increase it's value every ms.

My code currently looks like this, and isn't working (obviously) as it is concatenating the string. Is there any relatively straight forward way to implement this?

```
var num = '00:00:00';

setInterval(function(){
   num += '00:00:01'
}, 1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript seconds to time string with format hh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)

Comment: @ppasler yes, i saw this one, but how can you increase every second without concatenating the string?

Comment: You really want to update every millisecond? `setInterval(..., 1)`

Comment: @ppasler i think I'm going to have to increase that... machine keeps crashing

Comment: Every second should be enough, as you only show seconds.

Comment: @ppasler no i wanted to show ms -- see question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `+=` with a string adds a value to the end of a string. It's best to work with numbers. Set separate variables for the number of seconds, minutes and hours. If the number of one of them is in single digits, add a zero in front of it.

This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but it will work.

```js
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var hours   = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds === 60) {
        seconds = 0;       // Reset seconds and increase minutes
        minutes++;
    }
    if (minutes === 60) {
        minutes = 0;       // Reset minutes and increase hours
        hours++;
    }
    if (hours === 24) {     // A day has 24 hours
        hours = 0;
    }
  
    timer.innerHTML = [
                       (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours),
                       (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes),
                       (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds)
                      ].join(':');
},1);
```

```html
<p id="timer"></p>
```

Comment: nice man! exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! will give the green tick when i can

Comment: Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
var time=[0,0,0];
function increase(){
time[2]++;//secs
if(time[2]>=60){
  time[1]++;
  time[2]=0;
}
if(time[1]>=60){
  time[0]++;
  time[1]=0;
}
if(time[0]>=24){
  time[0]=0;
}
}
function show(){
 //if position has no ten digit, add a zero there, then place : between the digits
 return time.map(e=>e<10?"0"+e:e).join(":");
}
```

Use like this:

```
setInterval(increase,1000);
console.log(show());
```