# convert time through javascript and jquery in hrs

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this Code, I am getting the time as: 14:00

```
var starttime = ('00' + starttime.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + starttime.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
var endtime = ('00' + endtime.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + endtime.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

But I want Time in form of 12 hrs Like: 2:00 PM. What are the possibilities in javascript and jQuery? Help me I am newbie in this field.

Comment: Use moment.js library

Comment: already added that library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript seconds to time string with format hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)

Comment: not working with my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = new moment();
var time = date.format('hh:mm a');
console.log(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

use `.format('hh:mm a')` to get in 12 hour format

Comment: i am getting time in through this      var starttime = new Date(events.start);   so how can i use

Comment: @Arushi you are getting a Date() object right? if so you can pass that to `new moment(starttime);`

Comment: @Arushi try new moment(new Date(events.start));

Answer (score 1):

```
function fancyTimeFormat(time)
{   
    // Hours, minutes and seconds
    var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
    var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
    var secs = time % 60;

    // Output like "1:01" or "4:03:59" or "123:03:59"
    var ret = "";

    if (hrs > 0) {
        ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
    }

    ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
    ret += "" + secs;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ts = new Date(your timestamp);

    ts = moment(ts).format('hh:mm a');
```

where **H** means 24 hrs and you want **h**
using moment.js library

```
in your case,

starttime = moment(starttime ).format('hh:mm a');
endtime = moment(endtime).format('hh:mm a');
```

Comment: its showing time but after adding this    var starttimess = ('00' + starttimes.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + starttimes.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);  its not showing alert and time

Comment: @Arushi why are you declaring same variable name twice and if you need to convert your date to hh:mm then my answer above is enough

Answer (score 0):

You've said you're using moment.js.

That means you can do this:

```
var time = moment(date).format("hh:mm a");
```

Comment: its showing time but after adding this    var starttimess = ('00' + starttimes.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + starttimes.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);  its not showing alert and time