# How to convert seconds into human readable time lapse

Tags: node.js, performance

I have this function

```
const performance = require('perf_hooks');

var t0 = performance.now();

setInterval(printStatus, 20000);

function printStatus() {

     console.log(
    `Total records: ${count}`
  );
  console.log("Time elapsed" + (performance.now() - t0)/60000 + "minutes")
}
```

This prints minutes like this:
Time elapsed0.3334145895500978minutes

I want it to become human readable HH:MM:S
How do I make it happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss maybe this post help you

Comment: @gonzalo TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
const performance = require('perf_hooks');

var t0 = performance.now();

setInterval(printStatus, 20000);

function printStatus() {

     console.log(
    `Total records: ${count}`
  );
  const msElapsed = (performance.now() - t0);
  const hhmmss = (new Date(msElapsed)).toISOString().substr(11,8);
  console.log("Time elapsed " + hhmmss )
}
```

Comment: concise solution (t)