# How can I convert incoming seconds to hours in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, laravel-8, algolia

In my Laravel 8 project I have a page for content creators. These pages contain general information about content producers. I wanted to pull the data of content producers from Algolia and I made the Algolia link to my project. There is a section on the page that shows how many hours and how many minutes content producers have, but this data is kept in Algolia in seconds. That's why I want to show the data coming on the basis of this second in the form of hours and minutes on the screen.

**The data from Algolia is as follows. Seconds data also comes from: `"length"`**

```
{
  "id": 99,
  "user_id": 613,
  "isLearnBite": 0,
  "name": "Write the Brand Strategy of Your Business",
  "cover": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses/99/images/cover/513230_1642578467.jpg",
  "color": "#fefefe",
  "description": "Many solopreneurs struggle to clarify their business strategy and marketing goals because they can't define who they are and what they offer as a brand. With this mini-course, you will be able to understand the basics of branding and write yourself a brand strategy document which will help you make a solid start and stay on your track for long years.",
  "short_description": "A solid, strategic start for your small business or start-up.",
  "length": 6783,
  "order": 0,
  "status_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2022-01-18T07:14:42.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-01-19T12:48:29.000000Z",
  "custom_fields": {
    "dynamic_link": "https://omnicourse.page.link/cC8bZNQ6WhU1ahGS9"
  },
  "lectures_count": 27,
  "lecturer_name": "Nil Yalcinkaya",
  "lecturer_username": "nile_brand_academy",
  "lecturer_avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/613/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_985347_1638513165.jpg",
  "tags": [
    30,
    43,
    150,
    206
  ],
  "categories": [
    2
  ],
  "last_listened_data": null,
  "user_rating": 0,
  "isFavorited": false,
  "isBookMarked": false,
  "isCompleted": false,
  "creator_profile": {
    "name": "Nil Yalcinkaya",
    "username": "nile_brand_academy",
    "avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/613/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_985347_1638513165.jpg",
    "about": "Hi! \r\nI write brand strategies for digital start-ups of the future and design their visual brand identities. \r\nSee My Services: Nile Brand Design\r\nFollow & Join Our Community to Learn More about Branding: Nile Brand Academy",
    "custom_fields": {
      "email_octopus_id": "bc6ec095-69ec-11ec-96e5-06b4694bee2a",
      "email_octopus_last_update": "2022-03-26 00:48:58",
      "avatar_thumb_400*400": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/613/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_985347_1638513165.jpg",
      "linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nilyalcinkaya/",
      "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/nile.brand.design/",
      "twitter": "https://twitter.com/nilsyalcinkaya",
      "website": "https://www.nilebrand.design/"
    }
  },
  "_tags": [
    "App\\Course::99"
  ],
  "objectID": "App\\Course::99"
}
```

**I'm showing this time data here. - show.blade.php**

```
@if(isset($content['length']))
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-6">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <img src="/assets/images/icon-clock-black.svg" alt="">
            <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ $content['length'] }} hrs</span>
            <a href="{{ $content['length'] }}" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/icon-clock-black.svg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <img src="/assets/images/icon-list-black.svg" alt="">
            <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ $content['lectures_count'] }} Lessons</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

I guess I need to do this in **JS**, but I wanted to ask you because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: since that data is showed from a blade template.. maybe the best approach would be to just perform the required arithmetic there before echoing the value: `{{ $content['length'] / 3600 }}` (as long as you don't need to cast to number before the operation and with no further processing for better formatting the number)

Comment: This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-with-format-hhmmss

Comment: the question title is totally unrelated with the question itself.. and all the answers are going in that fake direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the Amount of Hours using JS.

Easiest way to do so will be using `Date` Object & `toISOString()` Method.

```js
const time = document.querySelector("#time");

const seconds = 6783;
let date = new Date(null);
date.setSeconds(seconds);

const [hours, minutes, sec] = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8).split(":");
time.textContent = `${hours} Hour(s), ${minutes} Minutes & ${sec} Seconds`;
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: it doesn't really address the context of the question.. the value is printed when a given blade template is rendered.. using javascript would require to have a routine running when the page is loaded and by the way this answer doesn't address that.

Comment: @DiegoD The Question clearly says that it needs to be done in JS & he doesn't know how to do that. Even the Title asks how to do it in JS & not PHP. So, please read the complete question before commenting.

Comment: @ShivangamSoni I know very well what the question asked and that's why I went deep enough to see the code content and figure out the answer was just addressing the title. Anyway if who asked is happy with that who am I to say the contrary. At this point I wonder why the question needed a whole body at all since it was enough the title itself