# How to transform seconds in minutes ? in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

My problems is that I have this value...75 seconds and I want to display in my Grid like 1:15 minutes... How can I do this ?

I'm trying this...

```
    xmlCttSemAcao = new XMLListCollection(event.result..CTT);
    var i:int = 0;

    for each(var node:XML in xmlCttSemAcao)
    {
        xmlCttSemAcao[i].@DUR_CTT = (xmlCttSemAcao[i].@DUR_CTT / 60) %60;
        i++;
    }

    xmlCttSemAcao.refresh();
    gp2.refresh();
```

But my result for this example is: 1:25

Another example...56 seconds is displaying 0.933333

Comment: In JavaScript, but the method transfers to ActionScript 3.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733227/javascript-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split it up a bit, then calculate seconds and minutes before putting them together:

```
for each(var node:XML in xmlCttSemAcao)
{
    var durCtt:int = xmlCttSemAcao[i].@DUR_CTT;
    var seconds:int = durCtt % 60;
    var minutes:int = durCtt / 60;
    var timeDisplay:String = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    xmlCttSemAcao[i].@DUR_CTT = timeDisplay;
    i++;
}
```