# Convert audio time to MM:SS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I am trying to convert seconds to MM:SS and for some reason it is not showing correctly.

`jQuery('#player-recorded-call').get(0).currentTime;` is to get `<audio>` current time position.

For example

`audioCurrentTime` was set to 326.459368 which SHOULD be 05:26 (MM:SS) but for some reason it has been calculated to 05:84 (`var dur`)

```
    var audioCurrentTime = jQuery('#player-recorded-call').get(0).currentTime;

    var minutes = "0" + Math.floor(audioCurrentTime / 60);
    var seconds = "0" + (audioCurrentTime - minutes * 60);
    var dur = minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2);

    $(".criteria-duration").html(dur);
```

I got this math example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26206645/791022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `audioCurrentTime` isn’t a whole number, `(audioCurrentTime - minutes * 60)` won’t be either, and you’ll end up with a string like `"0326.4593684"`. Taking the last two characters of that, you get `05:84`.

You can truncate `audioCurrentTime` first:

```
var seconds = "0" + (Math.floor(audioCurrentTime) - minutes * 60);
```

The `%` (modulus) operator is also nice:

```
var seconds = "0" + Math.floor(audioCurrentTime % 60);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to include HH: only if been over 60 minutes?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: Divide seconds by 3600 to get hours and check whether that’s `>= 1` before prepending it.

Answer (score 4):

Your are missing the `Math.floor` call for seconds and get the last 2 digit of it, that is 84.

Updated code shall be :

```
var audioCurrentTime = jQuery('#player-recorded-call').get(0).currentTime;

var minutes = "0" + Math.floor(audioCurrentTime / 60);
var seconds = "0" +  Math.floor(audioCurrentTime - minutes * 60);
var dur = minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2);

$(".criteria-duration").html(dur);
```