# minutes and seconds function outputting unwanted numbers to end if time contains milliseconds

Tags: javascript

I've used a **time to hours, minutes, seconds** function from here: [Javascript seconds to minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486026/5859909)

Which works fine, except for when the time has milliseconds on the end.

This is the current (semi-modified) **JS** block:

```js
var time = 122, // example time (2 minutes, 2 seconds)
  mins = ~~(time / 60),
  secs = time % 60;

 var hrs = ~~(time / 3600),
  mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60),
  secs = time % 60;

 var ft = "";

 if (hrs > 0) {
     ft += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
 }
 ft += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
 ft += "" + secs;
console.log(ft);
```

The above **JavaScript** block works completely fine. However, if I were to change `time` equal to `122.33`, it will print something like:

> 2:02.3299999999999983

How would I fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Forgot to mention that this is not for converting time zone. It is for converting seconds to minutes & seconds (and hours if the audio spans for that long).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: what you are expecting the result?

Comment: @prasad something like `2:02` (not including the seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply with `Math.round()` function it will rounded the values.

[Refer the link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp)

[Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=Math)

```js
var time = 122.33, // example time (2 minutes, 2 seconds)
  mins = ~~(time / 60),
  secs = time % 60;

 var hrs = ~~(time / 3600),
  mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60),
  secs = time % 60;

 var ft = "";

 if (hrs > 0) {
     ft += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
 }
 ft += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
 ft += "" +Math.round( secs);
console.log(ft);
```

Comment: Always welcome I given the Link its help full for Math calculation.I always learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

use `Math.trunc(time);` for example `Math.trunc(122.33);    // 122`

Comment: Haha, the above guy got in quicker. Sorry dude, but thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a **very** compelling reason, you shouldn't be writing time conversions/formatting yourself. See this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) for why.

Checkout the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library. If you want to do a bit more work and avoid a dependency, use the [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) built-in library.

e.g. with MomentJS

```
> var moment = require('moment');
> var x_seconds = 122.33;
> moment(moment.duration(x_seconds, 'second').asMilliseconds()).format("mm:ss.SSS");
'02:02.330'
```

Comment: .. this isn't for a time zone. it's for converting seconds in a song.

Comment: I know, was making a general point. Both libs will do conversions, as well as duration/diffs. Trying to roll this stuff yourself is buggy and will cause you pain down the road. Just use a lib and be done with it.

Comment: I'm not using a library for something this simple. it is incredibly pointless. especially when it's able to be done in one JavaScript block.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of solving your problem. But an easy way to do this is to try `.toFixed(n)`

For eg: `var x = 10/3 ; x.toFixed(3)` would give you precision to 3 decimal places.