# How to handle eslint no-param-reassign rule in Array.prototype.reduce() functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've recently added the eslint rule [`no-param-reassign`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign).

However, when I use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build out an object (empty object as `initialValue`), I find myself needing to modify the `accumulator` (first arg of callback function) on each callback iteration, which causes a `no-param-reassign` linter complaint (as one would expect it would).

```
const newObject = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((result, item, index) => {
  result[item] = index; // <-- causes the no-param-reassign complaint
  return result;
}, {});
```

Is there a better way to build out an object with `reduce` that doesn't modify the `accumulator` argument?

Or should I simply disable the linting rule for that line in my `reduce` callback functions?

Comment: Note, this is specifically because you've passed `"props": true` to the rule. By default it does not complain about this. If you don't want that behavior, seems like setting that to `false` is what you want? Or flag it with `// eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign.`

Comment: that's a good point @loganfsmyth. i'll do some re-examination to see if setting "props" to true is really what we want...

Comment: btw, there's a great conversation on this topic at https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/719

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Whenever I use `Array.prototype.reduce` I always name the "accumulator" parameter `accu`.  This convention conveniently allowed me to set my eslint rule:

```json
    "no-param-reassign": [
      "error",
      {
        "props": true,
        "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["accu"]
      }
    ],
```

If you have your own naming convention for this parameter, replace "accu" in the rule above with whatever you use, and eslint will not complain about modifying your accumulator.

Comment: Even though this answer is approved, I would discourage from taking this approach. 
Naming every reduce accumulator "accu" will lead to code that is hard to read. you should try to make your code explain itself instead (clean code). Even more confusion and potential mistakes will arise if you ever nest reduce functions.
Wrapping the block like `Zack Knopp` answer would be advised imo.

Comment: In every case I have encountered, there is enough context from the name of the variable to which the output will be assigned (and what's going on in the function) that it's not an issue. If the function is too complex where that isn't the case, it may make sense to refactor and take a different approach.

Comment: I agree with @Anj, the point above is pedantic in this regard.

Answer (score 36):

I just wrap the reduce functions in a lint rule disable block, ie:

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
const newObject = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((result, item, index) => {
  result[item] = index;
  return result;
}, {});
/* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer for performance reasons. I believe this is the optimal solution. No-param-reassign is a way to keep us from inducing side effects outside of scope, but the case of Array.reduce is an exception to issue of side-effects, since it is internally pure.

Answer (score 34):

One solution would be to leverage the [object spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)

```
const newObject = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((result, item, index) => ({
  ...result,
  [item]: index, 
}), {});
```

**Performance Warning!!** This is a [non-performant (`O(n^2`) solution](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) that should be avoided.

Comment: Is this really a good solution? Reducing an array with many elements, let's say 2000, would create as many new object instances, like 2000 in this case.

Comment: @Amida yes, it's very non performant solution - cause you can possibly have very large arrays. Instead of just using new (single) object you are creating new object each iteration what is very slow.

Comment: As other have said before, this is not performant. You should just disable the lint rule in that line. And perhaps ask the eslint folks to consider adding an exception specifically for Array.reduce

Comment: I agree that it's less performant, but it does make it a pure function with no side-effects, so that it could fit in to a functional-programming approach.

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could do `(result, item) => Object.assign({}, result, {[item]: whatever})` to create a new object on every iteration :-)

If you want to trick the linter, you could use `=> Object.assign(result, {[item]: whatever})` (which does the same as your current code but without an explicit assignment), but yeah I guess you should simply disable that rule.

Comment: yeah, that's kinda what i figured. maybe disabling the rule for that line is the best option...

Answer (score 2):

As I found no other reasonable solution, I just disable that single check:

```js
const newObject = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((result, item, index) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  result[item] = index;
  return result;
}, {});
```