# How to convert a JavaScript reduce method to use a filter method

Tags: javascript, filter, reduce

I have a reduce method done in JavaScript to combine the contents of an array of objects where there is a match with the same key.

For example:

```js
const data = [{
    "stage": "AT_CALLCENTER",
    "content": "Hello",
  },
  {
    "stage": "AT_CALLCENTER",
    "content": "Bye",
  },
  {
    "stage": "AT_SITE",
    "content": "Good",
  },
  {
    "stage": "AT_SITE",
    "content": "Morning",
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((val, item) => ({ ...val,
  [`${item.stage}`]: [...(val[item.stage] || []), item.content]
}), {});

console.log(result)
```

I was told by a friend that a filter can perform better; this is important because I'm expecting much more data in production, and this code is executed 2x per row.

How can I achieve the same functionality, but with a filter instead of a reduction? Or is filter not actually the better option?

Comment: `filter` can't perform better for this task. You can probably remove both spread syntaxes to avoid creating new object and arrays in every iteration.

Comment: actually, your `reduce()` implementation is correct, `filter()` cannot do the same

Comment: Thanks so I'm confused why the friend said his opinion about this reduce perform slower than a filter actually but I will keep the reduce then . I also will remove the spread syntax as no need that

Comment: You need to spread syntax here. If you want to remove it, you'd have to do `.reduce((val, item) => { if( val[item.stage]) val[item.stage].push(item.content) else val[item.stage] = [item.content]; return val  }, {})`

Comment: Or `.reduce((val, { stage, content }) => { val[stage] ??= []; val[stage].psuh(content); return val }, {})`

Comment: When I use `??= []` I get a syntax error that probably is not available in the novel version my project is at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some documentation](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) on why `reduce/spread` [is not considered](https://prateeksurana.me/blog/why-using-object-spread-with-reduce-bad-idea/) an optimal pattern.

But also don't use `filter` either - your result is an object, not an array (which is what `filter` returns). You can create your new data with a simple `for/of` loop so you don't introduce that unnecessary performance hit, and make the code easier to read too.

Note: `??=` is [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

```js
const data=[{stage:"AT_CALLCENTER",content:"Hello"},{stage:"AT_CALLCENTER",content:"Bye"},{stage:"AT_SITE",content:"Good"},{stage:"AT_SITE",content:"Morning"}];

const result = {};

for (const { stage, content } of data) {
  result[stage] ??= [];
  result[stage].push(content);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use that as the lint rules I have in the project I'm working on do not consent this kind of methods but nice stuff indeed

Comment: You could use `result[stage] = result[stage] || [];` if it doesn't like `??=`. @Jakub LNA is a relatively new feature.

Comment: Thanks we use still node 16 i believe that why

Answer (score 2):

I am really surprised, I was going to answer that no matter how much `filter` was used it was not going to be more efficient than `reduce`, but I was wrong.

I have done the test and here are the results: https://jsbench.me/v2l9zn3473/1

This is the code using `filter`, it is more complex, but it turns out to be faster:

```js
const stages = [...new Set(data.map(i => i.stage))]
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  stages.map(s => [s, data.filter(i => i.stage === s).map(i => i.content)])
)
```

However, using `for/of` is faster

Edit: As @Andy said, the problem is the way to use the `reduce` together with the `spread`, just do not use the `spread` and return the accumulator. You get a performance almost identical to `for/of`.

**This solution it's better**:

```js
const result = data.reduce((val, item) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign`
  val[item.stage] ??= [];
  val[item.stage].push(item.content);
  return val;
}, {});
```

Comment: How can I avoid no-param-reassign as I got this issue with my linter and I have strict rules

Comment: Honestly, I should disable that rule for the reduce accumulator. Use `// eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902167/11299601