# Session Timeout - results in minutes

Tags: javascript, php, session-timeout, minute

```js
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 2700; //seconds 45min

var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function() {
  _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
  _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onkeypress = function() {
  _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
  _idleSecondsCounter++;
  var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
  if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
  if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    //alert("Your Session Time expired. Please Login.");
    document.location.href = "logoff.php";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='SecondsUntilExpire'></div>
```

So from above i am getting output as 2699 ( its in seconds = 45min ) and  if no event happen its decrements ( 2698..2697..and so on  ) and if any event (mouse up..etc )  happen its back to 2699

But i need in minutes thats : **44:59, 44:58 ..and so on**

Comment: Check out this case for your formatting needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733227/javascript-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: i am using Firefox

Comment: @Scuzzy , thanks ...i tried that and working well ...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd code it to be readable

```
function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
    var remain = IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter;
    var remainMinutes = Math.floor(remain / 60);
    var remainSeconds = ('0' + (remain % 60)).substr(-2);
    if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = remainMinutes + ':' + remainSeconds; 
    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        //alert("Your Session Time expired. Please Login.");
        document.location.href = "logoff.php";
    }
}
```

uses

```
var remainSeconds = ('0' + (remain % 60)).substr(-2);
```

so that seconds are always two digits

Comment: Hey Jaromanda , thanks its working ...one more question session timeout event not working on all tab same ...i means say ...if i have open 2 tabs in same browser , so in one tab its 44:06 and on second tab its 44:58 ...if i refresh my first tab ..then it revert to 44:59 but if i see my second tab it showing 43:34....so my question is can i make a popup if timeout is less then 1 min .. saying you will be logout in 1 min and if user click ok he/she will be logout and if he No then its auto reset

Comment: no idea what you are asking here ... are you trying to synchronise the timeout in multiple browser tabs? use localStorage perhaps, or BroadcastChannel in firefox/chrome

Comment: yes synchronize same timeout in  all tabs ..if i refresh in one tab ...automatically reset all other tab

Comment: see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin) for an answer to that

Comment: yes i google and found localstorage .. but need time to build that logic ....hence for timing can i stop user been logout ..as if they have opened many tab ...so might be any one tab is not used and session will be timeout ..hence popup will stop them

Comment: ohh great will look in that....thanks

Comment: i tried :  if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = remainMinutes + ':' + remainSeconds; 
        
        var toald = oPanel.innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem("autoupdate",toald);
        document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("autoupdate");

    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        //alert("Your Session Time expired. Please Login.");
        document.location.href = "logoff.php";
    }   .....but its not working

Comment: well, you'll need more logic than just reading and writing localStorage I'm afraid

Comment: ohk ...thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseInt((IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter)/60) + ":" + (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter)%60;` to get achieve *hh:mm* effect

```js
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 2700; //seconds 45min

var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onkeypress = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
    if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = parseInt((IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter)/60) + ":";
        oPanel.innerHTML += (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter)%60<10?"0"+(IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter)%60:(IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter)%60; 
    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        alert("Your Session Time expired. Please Login.");
        //document.location.href = "logoff.php";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='SecondsUntilExpire'></div>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks and code updated. now it'll show `1:01`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this function

```
  var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 2700;
  alert(getMinutes(IDLE_TIMEOUT));
  function getMinutes(time){
       minutes = time/60;
       seconds = time%60;
       return ("00" + minutes).substr(-2)+":"+("00" + seconds).substr(-2);
 }
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ttqtfwp5/1/