# How to convert seconds to minutes after 60 secs passed in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, timer

````
  @Input() maxSeconds = 60;
  @Input() startSeconds = 0;
  @Output() alarmSnooze: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();  
  seconds: number;
  private everySecond$: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
  private stopTimer$: Subject<{}> = new Subject();
  private alarms: Array<number>;
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.alarms = [29, 59];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.everySecond$.pipe(takeUntil(this.stopTimer$))
      .subscribe((seconds) => {
        this.seconds = (this.startSeconds + seconds);
        if (this.alarms.includes(this.seconds)) {
          this.alarmSnooze.emit(this.seconds);
        }       
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      });
  }
}```
````

This is what i wrote as of now it just continues as seconds and keeps counting, but i want it to count to minutes.

Comment: Where exactly are you expecting minutes instead of seconds?

Comment: im sorry im not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: Have you checked the answers here: [Javascript seconds to minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3733227/9423231) ? What output would you want for e.g. `72 sec`?

Comment: use an object Date and the datePipe of Angular https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

ok here are some changes ive done

```
  @Input() startSeconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  @Input() secs = this.startSeconds - this.minutes * 60;
  // @Output() alarmSnooze: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();  
  seconds: number;

  private everySecond$: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
  private stopTimer$: Subject<{}> = new Subject();
  private alarms: Array<number>;
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.alarms = [29, 59];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.everySecond$.pipe(takeUntil(this.stopTimer$))
      .subscribe((seconds) => {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        // if (this.alarms.includes(this.seconds)) {
        //   this.alarmSnooze.emit(this.seconds);
        // }  
        if (this.seconds === 10){
          this.seconds = 0;
          this.minutes++;
        }     
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      });
  }
}
```

i now can get 60 secs to 1:00 but after that it starts counting seconds again, i belive that i am missing something in the "if" statement