# How to add a zero if the number of seconds is less than 10? After converting integer to minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch

Currently I am using the code below to express a time in seconds (900) in seconds and minutes (15 mins 0 Seconds).

I am wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this as trying to use the same method fails for the first timer.

```
function cddisplay() {
    // displays time in span
    document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = Math.floor(count / 60) + ":" + count % 60;
    if (scount % 60 >= 10) {
        document.getElementById('timespan1').innerHTML = Math.floor(scount / 60) + ":" + scount % 60;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('timespan1').innerHTML = Math.floor(scount / 60) + ":0" + scount % 60;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please explain a little more. Its unclear when its not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript seconds to minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733227/javascript-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: Unrelated, but it might be easier to read overall if you pulled out all the repeated math and DOM lookups.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: perhaps a typo in your code? you have a `scount` that's not defined anywhere