# How to change this countdown timer into minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code below, it works fine but I need to change the countdown timer into minutes and seconds. Something like this **59:59** and **09:09** when it's below 10. And thanks so much for the help.

```
var test = 3600;
$('button').click(function(){
if (localStorage.getItem("counter")) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("counter") <= 0) {
        var value = test;
    } 
    else {
        var value = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    }
  } 
    else {
        var value = test;
    }
    
    $('#divCounter').text(value);

var counter = function() {
    if (value == 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("counter", test);
        value = 0;
    } 
    else {
        value = parseInt(value) - 1;
        localStorage.setItem("counter", value);
    }
    
    $('#divCounter').text(value);
};

var interval = setInterval(function() { counter(); }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divCounter">3600</div>
<br>
<button>Start The Counter</button>
```

Comment: What are you struggling with at the moment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript seconds to minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733227/javascript-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One minute = total / 60.
Seconds = total % 60.

Add 0 if minutes or seconds below 10.
Just add this calculations before adding to html.

```js
var test = 3600;
$('button').click(function(){
if (localStorage.getItem("counter")) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("counter") <= 0) {
        var value = test;
    } 
    else {
        var value = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    }
  } 
    else {
        var value = test;
    }

    $('#divCounter').text(value);

var counter = function() {
    if (value == 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("counter", test);
        value = 0;
    } 
    else {
        value = parseInt(value) - 1;
        localStorage.setItem("counter", value);
    }
    var minutes = Math.floor(value / 60)
    var seconds = value % 60
    if (minutes<10) minutes = '0'+minutes      
    if (seconds<10) seconds = '0'+seconds    
    $('#divCounter').text(minutes+':'+seconds);
};

var interval = setInterval(function() { counter(); }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It's working but the add 0 below 10 doesn't work! it shows this `0{seconds}` if seconds is below 10. Could you resolve it please?

Comment: Fixed this bug. Thanks

Comment: Now it works fine! thanks so much for the help and answer accepted.