# How can I display the duration time of the video player in jQuery? Format like this: 00:00

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

//I've already tried this code but the result is not what I've want.

```
$video.on('timeupdate', function() {
      videoTimeFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
    });
    
function videoTimeFrame(currentTime, duration) {
      $total_time.text(currentTime);
      $duration_time.text(duration);
```

Comment: So you want to convert seconds to minutes and seconds?

Comment: `$total_time.text(new Date(currentTime * 1000).toISOString().substr(14, 5));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733227/javascript-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds