# I nee to add "0" before minutes <10 in Typescript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, time

I need to display the time and the minutes are not working correctly. It is returning 12:4, 2:3..when the minutes are less than 10 there is not 0. I tried adding the "0" like this:

```
var formattedTime = new Date(time + 'z');
    var hours = formattedTime.getHours();
    var amOrPm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = (hours % 12) || 12;

    var minutes = formattedTime.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) {
      ("0" + minutes)
    };
    
    var finalTime = eventDate +" "+ hours + ":" + minutes + " " + amOrPm;
```

Any help is welcome(I am new to coding). Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript seconds to minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733227/javascript-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: See Everts, because the alternative is not good and uses a string and a number with the same variable. Also forget that `var` exists, `let` or `const` instead. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKARAhlOMC8MBEiU+AUAugE4wBmIFAtplgCYAqAlvdnmHAO4wMWABT4ATAAYxYgLQSAnDIDME1mICMALgkBWTTvUA6CeoAsALXwBKANxlKMABYgArhQi4adRlBYcuhgDmcFAAEq7uwrb2VOj0APIUAAr0ns5uHgB8eOpiMAD8MADkSQCyRTCaxQCC5Xbp7p7CDR4ApDC5VjAAPt0dYnbkVPTsYC5YEFVj9ABGcFR90BSjgZ60DExwbJxwQSGlo+NwEFF27NQwwiNjEzAAPB0SXQDeJDDvMNdHHnj4EvgwADUn0OEzsAF8YjRRugADb+bjwJAoITYQEA-DAlpAgiaAHAr63YEYnFxRIpOygSAgWG7WEgQLCagw+E7KxAA

Answer (score 2):

The statement `("0" + minutes)` doesn't do anything. It does add a '0' to minutes, but you're not doing anything with the result. The problem is that you need to set the result of this statement in a new variable.

But here's an easier way to do this:

```js
const minutes = 5;
const minuteStr = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

Comment: Feedback on the downvote appreciated